# Convert DataFrame or Series of lists into one stacked DataFrame (or Series)

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, flatten

Having a `DataFrame` (or `Series`) consisting of lists, looking like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[[1,3], [2,3,4], [1,4,2,5]]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C']).T
print(df)
```

Output:

```
              0
A        [1, 3]
B     [2, 3, 4]
C  [1, 4, 2, 5]
```

How can I transform it into

```
   0
A  1
A  2
B  2
B  3 
B  4
C  1
C  4
C  2 
C  5
```

I've tried to use `apply()` but that didn't quite work. Can I implicitly convert that? I also tried to extract all number as tuples `[('A', 1), ('A', 3), ..]` for `from_records()` but I wasn't able to do that as well.

I think I could do it like this:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records(df[0].map(lambda x: [(0, v) for v in x]).sum())
```

but I don't know how to access the index.. note `(0, v)` should actually be something like `(x.index, v)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need flattening values in column and then [`repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.repeat.html) index by [`len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html) of `lists`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0:np.concatenate(df.iloc[:, 0].values.tolist())},
                  index=df.index.repeat(df[0].str.len()))
```

---

```
from  itertools import chain
df=pd.DataFrame({0:list(chain.from_iterable(df.iloc[:, 0].values.tolist()))}, 
                 index=df.index.repeat(df[0].str.len()))
```

---

```
print (df)
   0
A  1
A  3
B  2
B  3
B  4
C  1
C  4
C  2
C  5
```

**Timings**:

```
np.random.seed(456)

N = 100000
a = [list(range(np.random.randint(5, 20))) for _ in range(N)]
L = list('abcdefghijklmno') 
df = pd.DataFrame({0:a}, index=np.random.choice(L, size=N))
print (df)

In [348]: %timeit pd.DataFrame({0:np.concatenate(df.iloc[:, 0].values.tolist())}, index=df.index.repeat(df[0].str.len()))
1 loop, best of 3: 218 ms per loop

In [349]: %timeit pd.DataFrame({0:list(chain.from_iterable(df[0].values.tolist()))}, index=df.index.repeat(df[0].str.len()))
1 loop, best of 3: 388 ms per loop

In [350]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[:, 0].tolist(), index=df.index).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=1).to_frame().astype(int)
1 loop, best of 3: 384 ms per loop
```

Comment: I've updated my question with an example using `from_records()` which only has the problem that I'm not able to access the actual index of each element when I use `map()` .. any idea if it could work that way?

Comment: Hmmm, it is not possible this way :(

Comment: @displayname Just a note, my answer addresses completeness, so if you have any performance issues, consider taking a look at jezrael's first option :-)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thanks for the hint. Indeed I ran into a performance issue there. I'll check out jezrael's answer too.

Comment: @displayname - I test it and for biggere dataframes is faster first solution. Also timings was added to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `pd.DataFrame` + `stack` + `reset_index` + `to_frame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[:, 0].tolist(), index=df.index)\
                         .stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=1).to_frame()
df

     0
A  1.0
A  3.0
B  2.0
B  3.0
B  4.0
C  1.0
C  4.0
C  2.0
C  5.0
```